# Is it possible to load a debug verion of an ios app to test flight?

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight

When doing some testing on testflight we facing some crashes of our app. The crash reports provided in test flight are not very helpful because I can't see at which point in my app the crash happened. Also log output is not shown. Because of that I've tried to upload a debug version to testflight to provide it to at least the internal testers.
After the upload the debug version I received this email:

> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
> symbols in Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: _IOIteratorNext,
> _IOObjectRelease, _IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties, _IORegistryEntryGetChildIterator, _IOServiceGetMatchingServices, _IOServiceNameMatching, _kIOMasterPortDefault, _ptrace. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above,
> altering your method names will help prevent this app from being
> flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of
> the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included
> with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information,
> visit the Technical Support Information at

Is is in general not possible to upload debug versions to testflight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there is no problem uploading a Debug version to TestFlight. I expect that Flutter is using these non-public symbols in their Debug builds, but removing them in Release. ("In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app.")

See also: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64430

It comes from the Flutter Engine. See [IOKit.h](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/5dd3d444c370a363a01a595a7dfd018e0b26d159/shell/platform/darwin/ios/framework/Source/IOKit.h) where they import private methods if FLUTTER_RUNTIME_MODE is either DEBUG or PROFILE.